# Neighborhood of a connected components

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am looking for a way to get the neighbors (circle of a given radius) in terms of connected component (CC).

I want take a dicision based on the count of the numbers of connected components that entour a given connected component.

in the example, the objective is to classify the green CC, as red ones, because of the amount of red neighbours.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not about programming. Take some time to research the theory and come back with questions about your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way with Matlab is to use `find` after `regionprops`.
Compute the bounding box of all CC in your binary image BW:

```
CC_stats = regionprops(BW, 'BoundingBox');
```

Then, assuming a circle centered at `[x0,y0]` and of radius `r0`, find all CC that are (partially) in the circle:

```
BB_CC = reshape([CC_stats.BoundingBox],4,[]);
idxCC_close = find((sqrt((BB_CC(2,:)-x0).^2+(BB_CC(1,:)-y0).^2)<r0) ...
| (sqrt(((BB_CC(2,:)+BB_CC(4,:)-x0).^2+(BB_CC(1,:)-y0).^2)<r0) ...
| (sqrt((BB_CC(2,:)-x0).^2+(BB_CC(1,:)+BB_CC(3,:)-y0).^2)<r0) ...
| (sqrt(((BB_CC(2,:)+BB_CC(4,:)-x0).^2+(BB_CC(1,:)+BB_CC(3,:)-y0).^2)<r0));
```

(Edit:) You must reshape the elements of `CC_stats.BoundingBox` because this variable is the bare elements of all bounding boxes, put one after another.

Quite long to write, but basically you want the indexes of the CC which have at least one corner inside the circle, hence 4 tests.

Finally, the number of close CC is just `length(idxCC_close)`.

Comment: it's an interesting idea,
when i try to acces to CC_stats.BoundingBox(2), it show me : 
"Field reference for multiple structure elements that is
followed by more reference blocks is an error".

even with this stats(:,1).BoundingBox(2)
i get "Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing".

Comment: @BrainMarker Sorry, I edit my answer. Indeed, it raises an error as `CC_stats.BoundingBox` are the elements of the bounding boxes themselves. I've forgotten that point...

Answer (score 1):

You could get the centroid of each group and calculate the number of connected components where the Euclidean distance to the desired component is less than or equal the radius.

```
CC = regionprops(BW, 'Centroid');
dist = squareform(pdist(cell2mat({CC(:).Centroid}')));
```

`dist` will be a NxN matrix, where N is the number of connected components. `dist(a,b)` gives you the distance of component `a` to component `b` (Note that `dist(a,a)` is always zero).

Now you can get the number of the nearest components like this:

```
componentIndex = 14; % Example
numberOfNearest = nnz(dist(componentIndex ,:) <= radius) - 1;
```

Where `radius` is your circle radius, and the `-1` is to avoid counting the current component.